# CSS How to draw image with transparency instead of color?

Tags: css, image, transparency, pcx

I have a PCX-image with green background color rgb(41, 253, 46) and I need to show this color as a transparent one, when I display it via CSS.

I am not familiar with CSS or HTML and it taking few hours trying to find solution. Unsuccessfully though. Any ideas how to do this?

Restrictions:
1)use CSS 
2)do not change image file
3)use this image file (not copy of it)

```
span#smlogo
{
    icon-decorator: image;
    icon-image-src: /ui_art/smlogo.pcx;
    icon-image-t-end: 154px;

    display: inline-block;
    width: 390px;
    height: 154px;
}
```

The image itself:
[image: image itself converted .pcx->.jpg]

Comment: `icon...` is not valid CSS. You need `background-image` instead.

Comment: That is not actually CSS. It's RocketCSS, that is based on CSS2 and CSS3 specification with some advanced functionality to draw in-game user interface. But. Since it's based on CSS2 and have some functionality of CSS3, i hope there is a solution to do that.

Comment: Ins't easier to use Photoshop and replace the green with transparency?

Comment: If photoshop is not an option, then try [CSS masking/clip path](http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)

Comment: masking is an option i think, but couldn't find yet an option, that would create a mask with a particular color from image

Answer (score 1):

In order to show transparency, you will need to use

```
rgba(41,253,46,.5)
```

The .5 at the end is a random alpha value I chose. It could be between 0.0-1.0, with 1.0 being completely opaque.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Well. I do not want to make the whole picture transparent. I want to make it transparent ONLY there, where the color matches rgb(41, 253, 46).
I'll add an image for better understanding what i want to get.

Comment: The whole picture:
I have am .MPQ file, that contains resources. I have a code, that deals with these resources. People getting this .MPQ file from different sources, so i can modify it, but it will affects only for me.
So the solution is to change code, that display that resource. The code will be same for all people, since it on GitHub.